# Problem with installing Eclipse Plugin for ESP-IDF configuration on ubuntu 20.04.02

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, esp32, esp-idf

Problem :Configuration.Unable to copy rules for OpenOCD to system directory, try running the eclipse with sudo command

[Problem with ESP-IDF Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5EsD.png)
**Operating System:** ubuntu 20.04
**Java 17 and above** JDK Development Kit 20
**Eclipse** Eclipse Installer 2023‑03
**ESP-IDF** esp-idf-v5.0.2